# Add a custom header to ProxyPass requests

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, http-headers

I have a simple apache vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hello.local

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8810/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8810/
</VirtualHost>
```

All request to hello.local are proxyed to `http://localhost:8810/`.
What I'd like to do is add a header to the http request going to `http://localhost:8810/` with a value returned by an external command. Something like

`Header set MyHeader ${/usr/bin/an_external_program}`

Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You want to execute this external program during each request?

Comment: Yes. Or it could also be a "subrequest": a value returned by a cgi script or something similar. I'm aware of the performance implications.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok I got it.

First of all, the script that is executed and that is used to get the value to insert in the header. I created this as `/opt/apache/debug.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

#this script just loops forever and outputs a random string
#every time it receives something on stdin

while read
do
        cat /dev/urandom|head -c12|base64
done
```

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName light.nik

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteMap doheader prg:/opt/apache/debug.sh
        RewriteRule (.*) - [E=customheader:${doheader:},P]

        RequestHeader set customheader %{customheader}e

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

The backend service running on `http://localhost:8080/` receives the `customheader` with the value from the script.

The Apache documentation about using external program is [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg).